# Using jQuery, is there a way to set a string equal to itself but with some modification?

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
$('p').text($('p').text().replace('string A', 'string B'));
```

Looking for a simpler way of doing this. Is there a way to pull and redeclare a string in the same method?

Answer (score 2):

You can pass a function to `$.text` instead of a manual value. That function will receive the old value as one of the arguments. Just return whatever you'd like the new value to be from the function.

```js
$('p').text(function(index, text) {
  return text.replace('Hello', 'Good day');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>Hello, World!</p>
```